# Looping in groovy that incrementally with 10000

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm working with Groovy script that works in Jenkins. I'm wondering how the looping can be done to increase by `10000` for each run.
Let say the first day the value is `10000` and the second day `20000` follow by next day `30000`, `40000` and so on until next 10 days.

It's a bit hard if I'm doing it with random number that is hard to retrieve when the Jenkins job is done.

Answer (score 1):

You could do as following

```
int startFrom = 0
int limitValue = 100000
int incrementBy = 10000
startFrom.step limitValue, incrementBy, { 
      println it
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Period.between(LocalDate from, LocalDate to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#between-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalDate-) to calculate the distance between two dates expressed in days and multiply your initial value. Consider following script:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.Period

final int step = 10000
final int max = 100000
final LocalDate from = LocalDate.parse("2018-02-09")

(0..15).each {
    def now = LocalDate.now().plusDays(it)

    def days = Period.between(from, now).getDays() + 1
    def value = Math.min(step * days, max)

    println "Day ${it}: ${value}"
}
```

Here we specify the start date we will be comparing the distance with (February 9th 2018), then we loop from 0 to 15 just for test reasons and we specify `now` date as the current date plus current value from the loop (+0, +1, +2, ...). `Period.between(from, now).getDays() + 1` calculates our multiplier - in each step we will multiply `step` by the distance expressed in `days` (we have to start from 1, so `1 * 10000 == 10000`). We also use  `Math.min(step * days, max)` safeguard (where `max == 100000`) so the value we take cannot be greater than the one defined in `max` variable. When you run following script you will see something like this in the console:

```
Day 0: 10000
Day 1: 20000
Day 2: 30000
Day 3: 40000
Day 4: 50000
Day 5: 60000
Day 6: 70000
Day 7: 80000
Day 8: 90000
Day 9: 100000
Day 10: 100000
Day 11: 100000
Day 12: 100000
Day 13: 100000
Day 14: 100000
Day 15: 100000
```

Of course in your Groovy script you can get rid of the loop and use:

```
def now = LocalDate.now()
```

When you calculate your final value like that you will get it incremented each day by `10000` until `100000`. Hope it helps.